# Accessing a user control from outside

Tags: wpf

I have a user control in WPF its simply has a grid and in the main form i have a button that do something with the selected row of that grid. The problem is when i use this command in my Button

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AlarmContainer.AlarmGrid ,Path=SelectedItem}
```

I cant access selected item in that DataGrid. What should i do ? i dont wanna use C# im looking for a WPF solution to this.

Comment: You can't access nested elements like this in XAML solution. Instead try binding to bound property in ViewModel to which dataGrid's SelectedItem is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AlarmContainer+AlarmGrid ,Path=SelectedItem}
```